# Can I make waiting Quartz Jobs fire in the order they were triggered?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have an application using the Quartz Scheduler to schedule jobs. The application is currently running Quartz version 1.6.2. My JobStore is org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX with an Oracle database backing it. Clustering is turned on, but there's only one scheduler using the database. My Quartz threadPool is configured as follows:

```
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
```

My jobs are long running, so it's fairly common to have 5 jobs running (the maximum allowed by my thead pool) when triggers fire new jobs. The newly triggered jobs misfire and I see log messages like the following:

```
2011-05-20 04:09:30,097 INFO  [QuartzScheduler_scheduler-servername-111305822374881_MisfireHandler] o.q.p.h.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin - Trigger DEFAULT.JobName1 misfired job DEFAULT.DEFAULT  at:  04:09:30 05/20/2011.  Should have fired at:  04:08:29 05/20/2011
2011-05-20 04:09:30,120 INFO  [QuartzScheduler_scheduler-servername-111305822374881_MisfireHandler] o.q.p.h.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin - Trigger DEFAULT.JobName1 misfired job DEFAULT.DEFAULT  at:  04:09:30 05/20/2011.  Should have fired at:  04:09:30 05/20/2011
2011-05-20 04:09:30,125 INFO  [QuartzScheduler_scheduler-servername-111305822374881_MisfireHandler] o.q.p.h.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin - Trigger DEFAULT.JobName2 misfired job DEFAULT.DEFAULT  at:  04:09:30 05/20/2011.  Should have fired at:  04:08:30 05/20/2011
2011-05-20 04:09:30,138 INFO  [QuartzScheduler_scheduler-servername-111305822374881_MisfireHandler] o.q.p.h.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin - Trigger DEFAULT.JobName2 misfired job DEFAULT.DEFAULT  at:  04:09:30 05/20/2011.  Should have fired at:  04:09:30 05/20/2011
2011-05-20 04:11:29,998 INFO  [QuartzScheduler_scheduler-servername-111305822376676_MisfireHandler] o.q.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX - Handling 2 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.
```

Once a running job finishes, one of the misfired jobs will get picked up and run normally. However, Quartz seems to pick up a misfired job randomly, with no regard to the order the jobs had been originally scheduled to execute. Ideally, I'd like them to be picked up in the order they were supposed to have run, based on their original fire times.

Is it possible to make my waiting (misfired) jobs get fired in the order they were triggered once space in the Quartz ThreadPool becomes available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When quartz handles a trigger that has missed it's fire time it will update the `nextFireTime` of the trigger. By default a trigger will be considered missed if it's nextFireTime is over 60 seconds in the past. Missed triggers should still be selected based on nextFireTime and priority order but I'm guessing it seems random because some triggers have been updated and others haven't.

I would suggest increasing the `org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold` property. See http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigRAMJobStore.html (although the property is identical for all JobStores). This should make it less likely for your triggers to be re-scheduled.

Comment: I can't really test this because I got a new job, haven't used quartz in years, and can't be bothered to set up a test project just to see if this works. However, I'm impressed that you've bothered to answer a 5-year old question, and your answer seems helpful, so I'm gonna go ahead and mark this as solved :)

Comment: I was having a similar issue so was searching stack overflow. In the end I dug through the code and figured out myself but thought I would leave this here in case anyone else was searching for the answer in the future.

Comment: @JonQuarfoth What worked for you in the end? I'm scheduling 10s of thousands of job and job will be long running as I need to migrate blob from location to another and those blobs can be as big as 100GB. I'm planning to use Quartz clustering so that when master schedules the job, slaves will keep working on those jobs and I don't really care about miss fire since I just care about the job getting picked by one of the slaves in the end. Maybe I can set a ridiculously large misfire threshold value. Please let me know what you guys think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I sounds like you are running into a misfiring scenario (a scenario where there are more jobs ready to be executing than there are worker threads).  Set the misfire instruction and/or priority property on the triggers to change how each behaves after it has past its fire time.

Also, you could consider increasing the misfire threshold, which would change the amount of time that a trigger can be "late" waiting for a thread to execute on before it is considered misfire (and has its misfire instruction applied to it).

> Is it possible to make my waiting (misfired) jobs get fired in the order they were triggered once space in the Quartz ThreadPool becomes available?

The "do nothing" instructions will leave the fire times as-is.

Comment: It's definitely a misfire scenario - I've updated the question to be a bit more specific on that point. Is there a misfire instruction that would make the misfired jobs get picked up in the order that they were originally fired in?

Comment: The javadoc for the MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_DO_NOTHING  misfire reads as follows: "Instructs the Scheduler that upon a mis-fire situation, the CronTrigger wants to have it's next-fire-time updated to the next time in the schedule after the current time, but it does not want to be fired now." Perhaps I misunderstand, but that sounds to me like the job would just skip firing and do nothing until the next time it's triggered. This is not what I want. I want the job to run as soon as there are are threads available, but with the longest-waiting jobs running first if there are multiple misfired jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the quartz [thread pool](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/quartz/simpl/SimpleThreadPool.java.html) , it uses a wait()/notify() loop, which is not fair, and will randomly select a new thread when multiple threads are waiting.

You could use your own instance of ThreadPool which is fair.  Copy the code from SimpleThreadPool, but replace the locking around nextRunnableLock with a java.util.ReentrantLock, passing true to the fair constructor.  In your modified SimpleThreadPool, use ReentrantLock.lock()/unlock() instead of synchronized, and use ReentrantLock.newCondition().signal()/await() instead of wait/notify, and it might solve your problem.

Comment: Those threads in the pool do not have jobs assigned to them, so the fairness you are talking about doesn't matter.  Whichever of those threads come free first, will run the next job.

Comment: I think the fairness comes from threads outside the thread pool, runInThread and blockForAvailableThreads both wait unfairly.  What did you mean when you said, "when my thread pool is maxed out"

Comment: runInThread() and blockForAvailableThreads() are both called from the same thread - there are not multiple threads waiting for the outcome of those methods, so 'fairness' of wait()/notify() do not matter. (Only one thread services/utilizes the thread pool).

Comment: I've edited the question a bit to provide more information. By "My thread pool is maxed out" I mean that the Quartz threadpool is out of worker threads to run jobs with, causing newly triggered jobs to misfire.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a `CronTrigger`, the method `updateAfterMisfire()` may re-schedule the task at `new Date()` case `MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_ONCE_NOW` policy.

If several task are misfired, several of them may be rescheduled at the same time (same millisecond), because computer runs fast.

As a consequence, and if no priority defined, the scheduler will pick-up the first next task, all with same `NextFireTime`, according to key or full name.

`updateAfterMisfire()` method should have re-schedule the task to a unique `date` using a `Thread.sleep(25)`, as an example.